# after() appending json data in reverse order

Tags: jquery

I want to append some data after an element in my markup for which I am using after() method. My json is as below (in a separate file)-

The problem is, it reverses the order of items and display them as 3 2 1 instead of 1 2 3! Can anyone please help me understand why and how can I fix this?

```js
const data = [{
  "testData": {
    "one": "1",
    "two": "2",
    "three": "three"
  }
}]


const json = data[0].testData;

for (const key in json) {
  var listItem = `<div><p>${key}</p><p>${json[key]}</p></div>`;
  $("hr").after(listItem);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>SAMPLE</h2>
<hr>
```

Comment: Use append `$("hr").append(listItem);`

Comment: @mplungjan If you inspect the markup it will get appended inside the <hr> and the markup will render as <hr><p></p><p></p></hr> .I want the structure to look like <hr><p></p><p></p> . If I prepend() then the order works properly. I don't understand this behavior.

Comment: Read the dupe and experiment. Also [RTM](https://api.jquery.com/append/), [RTM](https://api.jquery.com/prepend/),[RTM](https://api.jquery.com/after/),  [RTM](https://api.jquery.com/before/),

Comment: I mean before() sorry not prepend(). I have tried all these methods. That is why I posted this query. I simply want the div to be added AFTER the hr tag ( and not inside it) .

Comment: @HarshVardhanBandta did you figure it out? I' facing the same issue